# Can "do I" be used in the middle of a phrase as an affirmative sentence?

Tags: do

I am revising an English text and found a phrase on this text:

> Why do ye say: “Not even at the request of God **do I** forgive.”? Do not say ye that!

from the [original](https://www.apelosurgentes.com.br/pt-br/mensagens/5) Portuguese version:

> Por que dizeis: “nem com o pedido de Deus **eu** perdôo.”? Não digais isso!

I know that in English, a phrase beginning with:
**"Do I ... ?"** Means that it is a question.

My question is:
Can "do I" be used in the middle of a phrase as an affirmative sentence? Is this gramatically correct?
Or should this be rewritten in another way, how could this be written to be correct?

Comment: I'd keep the *do I* as it is. It fits nicely with the formality.

Comment: It's correct; with a negative adverbial at the front, we invert: https://blogs.transparent.com/ingles/2014/09/19/advanced-english-inversion-with-negative-adverbs-and-adverbial-phrases/

Comment: I would forget using "ye". The Portuguese is merely using a plural you. Trying to sound Biblical could be a mistake, overall. Language names take capital letters. "Do not  say ye that" that is completely wrong. Frankly, the proofreading should be done by a native English speaker. As a professional into-English proofreader and translator from Portuguese, this kind of thing is particularly disheartening. On the other hand, since this is usually fundamentalist stuff, I shouldn't care....

Comment: "Not even ... do I..." is very formal in English and old-fashioned sounding; I wouldn't expect to find it outside old books. Far more common is "Even" with a negative e.g. "Even at the request of God, I don't/won't/wouldn't forgive..."

Comment: In some cases "Do I ever!" means an emphatic "yes!". eg. "Do you remember Bob? Do I ever!". See https://www.phrases.org.uk/bulletin_board/51/messages/172.html

Comment: @StuartF - ye is pretty old-fashioned, as well.

Comment: The use of *do I* here is correct in modern English, though somewhat formal. Using *ye* in modern standard English is incorrect; the first one should be *you* and the second one should be omitted. There may be dialects where *ye* is used in this way, but I don't think OP's usage is correct even for Elizabethan English, though I stand to be corrected.

Comment: 'Would I' is much more common than 'do I', I would suggest.

Comment: @NigelJ - I find the meaning a bit different.